# Decompress bz2 files

Tags: python, compression

I would like to decompress the files in different directories which are in different routes.
And codes as below and the error is invalid data stream. Please help me out. Thank you so much.

```
import sys
import os
import bz2
from bz2 import decompress

path = "Dir"
for(dirpath,dirnames,files)in os.walk(path):
   for file in files:
       filepath = os.path.join(dirpath,filename)
       newfile = bz2.decompress(file)
       newfilepath = os.path.join(dirpath,newfile)
```

Comment: It looks like some of your variables are mixed up in that code.  Otherwise, [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bz2.html) says decompress takes data, not a file name: `bz2.decompress(data)`

Answer (score 27):

`bz2.decompress` takes compressed **data** and inflates it. You pass a filename, not the data in the file!

Do this instead:

```
zipfile = bz2.BZ2File(filepath) # open the file
data = zipfile.read() # get the decompressed data
newfilepath = filepath[:-4] # assuming the filepath ends with .bz2
open(newfilepath, 'wb').write(data) # write a uncompressed file
```

Comment: There still exits error *file is not ready for writing* Thanks

Answer (score 27):

bz2.compress/decompress work with binary data:

```
>>> import bz2
>>> compressed = bz2.compress(b'test_string')
>>> compressed
b'BZh91AY&SYJ|i\x05\x00\x00\x04\x83\x80\x00\x00\x82\xa1\x1c\x00 \x00"\x03h\x840"
P\xdf\x04\x99\xe2\xeeH\xa7\n\x12\tO\x8d \xa0'
>>> bz2.decompress(compressed)
b'test_string'
```

In short - you need to process file contents manually. In case you have very large files you should prefer using `bz2.BZ2Decompressor` to `bz2.decompress`, because the latter requires that you store the entire file in a byte array.

```
for filename in files:
    filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
    newfilepath = os.path.join(dirpath,filename + '.decompressed')
    with open(newfilepath, 'wb') as new_file, open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
        decompressor = BZ2Decompressor()
        for data in iter(lambda : file.read(100 * 1024), b''):
            new_file.write(decompressor.decompress(data))
```

You can also use `bz2.BZ2File` to make this even simpler:

```
for filename in files:
    filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
    newfilepath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename + '.decompressed')
    with open(newfilepath, 'wb') as new_file, bz2.BZ2File(filepath, 'rb') as file:
        for data in iter(lambda : file.read(100 * 1024), b''):
            new_file.write(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
for file in files:
    archive_path = os.path.join(dirpath,filename)
    outfile_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename[:-4])
    with open(archive_path, 'rb') as source, open(outfile_path, 'wb') as dest:
        dest.write(bz2.decompress(source.read()))
```

Comment: with open(archive_path, 'rb') as source, open(outfile_path, 'wb') as dest:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax .There still is an error.Thanks a lot

Comment: This is python3 syntax. Try: `from __future__ import with_statement`. If this still doesn't work, break the `ẁith` statement in two steps, like in Juraj Ivančić's anser

Comment: Too late - I changed mine to use chained with statements after seeing your response. Did not know about that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is much faster for large files because it incrementally writes the output, without storing the entire decompressed file in memory:

```
import bz2,shutil
filepath = 'test.txt.bz2'
with bz2.BZ2File(filepath) as fr, open(filepath[:-4],"wb") as fw:
    shutil.copyfileobj(fr,fw)
```

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49073452/3427777