# Possible to decompress bz2 in python to a file instead of memory

Tags: python, compression

I've worked with decompressing and reading files on the fly in memory with the `bz2` library.  However, i've read through the documentation and can't seem to just simply decompress the file to create a brand new file on the file system with the decompressed data without memory storage.  Sure, you could read line by line using BZ2Decompressor then write that to a file, but that would be insanely slow. (Decompressing massive files, 50GB+).  Is there some method or library I have overlooked to achieve the same functionality as the terminal command `bz2 -d myfile.ext.bz2` in python without using a hacky solution involving a subprocess to call that terminal command?

Example why bz2 is so slow:

Decompressing that file via bz2 -d: 104seconds

Analytics on a decompressed file(just involves reading line by line): 183seconds

```
with open(file_src) as x:
    for l in x:
```

Decompressing on the file and using analytics: Over 600 seconds (This time should be max 104+183)

```
if file_src.endswith(".bz2"):
    bz_file = bz2.BZ2File(file_src)
    for l in bz_file:
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use the `bz2.BZ2File` object which provides a transparent file-like handle.

(edit: you seem to use that already, but don't use `readlines()` on a binary file, or on a text file because in your case the block size isn't big enough which explains why it's slow)

Then use `shutil.copyfileobj` to copy to the write handle of your output file (you can adjust block size if you can afford the memory)

```
import bz2,shutil

with bz2.BZ2File("file.bz2") as fr, open("output.bin","wb") as fw:
    shutil.copyfileobj(fr,fw)
```

Even if the file is big, it doesn't take more memory than the block size. Adjust the block size like this:

```
shutil.copyfileobj(fr,fw,length = 1000000)  # read by 1MB chunks
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that, I edited my original post to why I was against reading line by line of the compressed bz2 file and why it was so slow in my testing

Comment: Great solution.  Even beat out `bz2 -d` Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

For smaller files that you can store in memory before you save to a file, you can use `bz2.open` to decompress the file and save it as an uncompressed new file.

```
import bz2

#decompress data
with bz2.open('compressed_file.bz2', 'rb') as f:
    uncompressed_content = f.read()

#store decompressed file
with open('new_uncompressed_file.dat', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(uncompressed_content)
   f.close()
```