# Unzipping all .bz2 files in each folder and subfolder in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the code below which starts at a directory and is suppose to go into each folder, open cmd and exec the statement below.

I can see it going into each directory but the cmd screen flashes but nothing is extracted. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import os

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.', topdown = True):
    os.system('7z e *.bz2')
    print(dirpath)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Check this link, may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963352/decompress-bz2-files

Answer (score 2):

You should make use of the `dirpath` and `filenames` variables while iterating through the `os.walk` generator:

```
import os
for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk('.', topdown = True):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.bz2'):
            os.chdir(dirpath)
            os.system('7z e ' + os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - this seems to work, can you tell me where the output is being saved as after the command is run, there seems to be no file in the folder? thanks

Comment: `'.'` refers to the current folder, so you should look at where your Python starts. Otherwise you should specify an absolute path instead of `'.'` for `os.walk` to search from.

Comment: yea i have specified the path to start from  `'..\\2018\\04'` and walk all folders from 04 onwards - but there seems to be no output there

Comment: I see. If you want the output to be where the 7z files are then you should use `os.chdir` first before extraction. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Comment: Actually i found out that the files are being save to `'...2018\\04\\fileName'` and because the files have the same name it stops and asks me for option.