# How to extract Bzip2 file in python

Tags: python, zip, tar, bzip2, bzip

I am writing program which fetch extension of filename from string than download it and extract it, I am able to do it with Tar.gz and zip type of compression but while extracting Bz2 type of file i am able to read file and transfer data to new file in same directory but what i would like is to create folder like zipfile and tarfile using something like 'ExtractAll" and extract file in it, but i am unable can anyone help

```
def bz2_download(*args):
    mystring_zip = ' '.join(args)
    print('{} Bz2 file Download Started!!!'.format(mystring_zip.split('/')[-1].split('.')[-2]))
    r = requests.get(mystring_zip)
    filename = mystring_zip.split('/')[-1]  # this will take only -1 splitted part of the url

    with open(filename, 'wb') as output_file:
        output_file.write(r.content)
    print('{} Bz2 file Download Completed!!!'.format(mystring_zip.split('/')[-1].split('.')[-2]))
    path_zip = mystring_zip.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
    print(path_zip, '+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')

    extract_dir = path_zip
    print('--------------------------{} extraction Started----------------------------------'.format(extract_dir))
    os.mkdir(path_zip)
    with open(path_zip, 'wb') as new_file, open(filename, 'rb') as file:

        decompressor = _bz2.BZ2Decompressor()
        for data in iter(lambda: file.read(100 * 1024), b''):
           a = new_file.write(decompressor.decompress(data))
        print(a, '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111')
    if extract_dir:
        print('---------------------------{} extraction completed----------------------------------'.format(extract_dir))
    else:
        print('---------------------------{} extraction Failed----------------------------------'.format(extract_dir))
```

Here is my Tar.gz code which download the file and extract it to a folder, want to do something similar with bzip2 file

```
def tar_download(*args):
    mystring_tar = ' '.join(args)
    print('{} Tar.gz file Download Started!!!'.format(mystring_tar.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]))

    r = requests.get(mystring_tar)
    filename = mystring_tar.split('/')[-1]
    with open(filename, 'wb') as output_file:
        output_file.write(r.content)
    print(' {} Tar.gz file Download Completed!!!'.format(mystring_tar.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]))
    path_tar = mystring_tar.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]

    extract_dir = path_tar
    print('---------------------------{} extraction Started----------------------------------'.format(extract_dir))
    thetarfile = tarfile.open(filename, mode="r|gz")
    thetarfile.extractall(extract_dir)
    if extract_dir:
        print('---------------------------{} extraction Complete----------------------------------'.format(extract_dir))
    else:
        print('---------------------------{} extraction Failed----------------------------------'.format(extract_dir))
```

Comment: The error  message is telling you what your problem is -- the bz2 class doesn't include a method called `extractall`.

Comment: So is there anyway i can extract Bz2 type file in working directory?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963352/decompress-bz2-files

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html#bz2.BZ2File for enlightenment